# ReportLab setting reference line on lineplot

Tags: reportlab

I would like to set reference line parallel with x axe with y value of first data in data array. 
I have a problem getting position of first record in my line plot. I tried with scale() but scale-ing is not performed properly.  Any thoughts?

I tried with this:

```
sensor_readings = [(1425294710, 4187L), (1425375419, 4181L), (1425456126, 4188L), (1425536836, 4209L), (1425617542, 4204L)]
reportChart = GridLinePlot()
reportChart.xValueAxis = XValueAxis()
width = pagesizes.letter[0] - 4*cm
height = pagesizes.letter[1] - 7*cm
reportChart.lines.strokeWidth = 0
reportChart.x = cm
reportChart.y = cm
reportChart.height = height
reportChart.width = width
reportChart.joinedLines = 0
reportChart.data = res_graph_data
reportChart.background.strokeColor = colors.gray

reportChart.lineLabels.fontSize           = 6
reportChart.lineLabels.boxStrokeWidth     = 0.5
reportChart.lineLabels.visible            = 1
reportChart.lineLabels.boxAnchor          = 'c'
reportChart.lineLabels.angle              = 0
reportChart.lineLabelNudge                = 10

reportChart.yValueAxis.labels.fontName    = 'DroidSans'
reportChart.yValueAxis.tickRight          = 0
reportChart.yValueAxis.maximumTicks       = 10
reportChart.yValueAxis.tickLeft           = 3
reportChart.yValueAxis.valueMax           = None
reportChart.yValueAxis.valueMin           = None
reportChart.yValueAxis.rangeRound         = 'both'
reportChart.yValueAxis.valueSteps         = None
reportChart.yValueAxis.valueStep          = None
reportChart.yValueAxis.forceZero          = 0
reportChart.yValueAxis.labels.fontSize    = 7
reportChart.yValueAxis.labels.dy          = 0
reportChart.yValueAxis.avoidBoundFrac     = 0.1
reportChart.yValueAxis.requiredRange      = 1

reportChart.xValueAxis.labelTextFormat        = convert_seconds
reportChart.xValueAxis.labels.fontName        = 'DroidSans'
reportChart.xValueAxis.labels.fontSize        = 7
reportChart.xValueAxis.valueSteps             = None
reportChart.xValueAxis.gridStrokeWidth        = 0.25
reportChart.xValueAxis.labels.angle           = 90
reportChart.xValueAxis.maximumTicks           = 20
reportChart.xValueAxis.tickDown               = 3
reportChart.xValueAxis.minimumTickSpacing     = 10
reportChart.xValueAxis.visibleGrid            = 0
reportChart.xValueAxis.gridEnd                =   0
reportChart.xValueAxis.gridStart              = 0
reportChart.xValueAxis.labels.angle           = 45
reportChart.xValueAxis.labels.boxAnchor       = 'e'
reportChart.xValueAxis.labels.dx              = 0
reportChart.xValueAxis.labels.dy              = -5

readingChart.xValueAxis.valueMin = datetime_min
readingChart.xValueAxis.valueMax = datetime_max
readingChart.xValueAxis.configure([sensor_readings])
readingChart.yValueAxis.configure([sensor_readings])
readingChart.joinedLines = 1
readingDrawing.add(readingChart)
reference_axe = XValueAxis()
pos_x = readingChart.x
pos_y = readingChart.yValueAxis.scale(sensor_readings[0][1])
reference_axe.setPosition(pos_x, pos_y, width)
reference_axe.strokeColor = colors.green
reference_axe.valueMin = datetime_min
reference_axe.valueMax = datetime_max
readingDrawing.add(reference_axe)
story.append(readingDrawing)
story.append(PageBreak())
```

This is what I would like to achieve:
[desired reference line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXo5H.png)

Comment: Could you post your code and an image showing what you actually want to achieve, this way it is easier for others to help you out.